# Home router config to allow for UDP broadcast

Tags: home-networking, udp, broadcast

I have a homegrown piece of software that "listens" to UDP traffic at 255.255.255.255:5010. It works just great on my home network, but does not work on other people's networks. I think that my equipment allows this sort of traffic through, while theirs does not.

How would I find out this setting? Is this a commonly "blocked" thing?

Also, I realize that this might not be a great way to send data, but I have no control on the server side, only the client side and the network.

I am on FIOS equipment (actiontec routers) looking for a "switch" to flip that would allow me to configure the other networks to work like mine.

These are not complex networks, there is a single router where the cable comes into the house and the other equipment (computers, tablets etc) are wired or wireless to that piece of hardware.

**UPDATE:**

On my network I have 3 "machines". Server 1, Server 2 and a super light client running on a Droid. Server 1 can send the data to the network (via PacketPlayer and a WireShark PCAP file). The Droid receives just fine. When I move the same setup to Server 2, the client does not get the data.

Maybe it is the firewall on Server 2 that is configured differently that Server 1?

Comment: When talking about other people's networks, do you mean that _both_ the sender and receiver are on the same network? Also, are they in fact in the same broadcast domain? Generally a broadcast will only reach other ports of the same switch/hub/bridge, but will not cross a router. (Home net devices are both-in-one.)

Comment: Does your listener simply bind to '*:5010', or does it specifically limit itself by binding to '255.255.255.255:5010'? If it's the latter, then the problem may be on the sender side. Some OSes' network stacks don't really let you send to the 255.255.255.255 address; instead, they translate it into the subnet-broadcast address for each locally-connected subnet (e.g. 192.168.0.255).

Comment: I put more info up in the question. But to answer the responses, sender and receiver are on the same network and subnet. My listener (Android Java) is binding a datagram listener to port 5010 only. I only have control over the server's general configuration (not the software sending the data), the receiver and the network. I am starting to think that this is a config issue on the server side - maybe maybe firewall?